# What is the grammatical structure of "Il est de formation classique"?

Tags: grammaire

In the following sentence:

> Il est de formation classique.

The translation I found is *He is classically trained.*, but I don't understand the grammatical structure of the sentence.

It is clear that *il* is a subject and *est* is a verb. And I think *classique* is an adjective that modifies *formation* (noun). But why is *formation*, which is a feminine noun, used in the form of *de formation*, not *de la formation*?

And also, why does the sentence mean *trained* in English? For me, *It is the classical formation.* sounds more natural...

Comment: Could you add more context?

Comment: I'm pretty sure 'formation' is a faux ami here.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Here is likely the context (or lack of) : https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/583502/Il-est-de-formation-classique

Comment: Yes the link of @jlliagre is correct, there is no other information except the sentence.

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote?

Comment: It is offtopic and I'm no native speaker but _He is classically trained_ is accurate imho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Être de [nom] [adjectif]" est dans ce cas-ci employé en remplacement de "Avoir un(e) [nom] [adjectif]". Dans chaque cas l'adjectif et le nom peuvent être inversés.

> Il est de formation classique = Il a une formation classique
>
> Il est de constitution faible = Il a une faible constitution

La phrase "It is the classical formation" n'a pas du tout le même sens, parlant de la formation en soi mais sans parler de la personne qui aurait reçu cette formation.

Comment: You mention that "Dans chaque cas l'adjectif et le nom peuvent être inversés," but only your second, "consitution/faible" example seems to illustrate this inversion. Is "Il a une classique formation" even possible? (It would sound weird to me, as opposed to "... faible construction," which does sound very natural to me.) Thanks.

Comment: Some constructions indeed sound weirder than others and are less idiomatic, but the inversion is anyway grammatically correct. Indeed "Il a une classique formation" is, also to me, in the first group while "Il a une faible constitution" is in the second and actually even sounds better (to me at least) than "Il a une constitution faible".

Answer (score 2):

> Il est de formation classique.

Cette phrase est composée

- d'un sujet : Il
- d'un verbe d'état : est
- d'un groupe nominal prépositionnel : de formation classique

Dans cette phrase, le groupe nominal prépositionnel a une fonction d'*attribut du sujet*.

> But why is formation, which is a feminine noun, used in the form of de formation, not *de la formation*?

Le déterminant peut être facultatif avec un attribut du sujet.

> Il est de formation classique = Il a une formation classique
>
> #### Laurent S.

Ces phrases ont *presque* la même signification. La première phrase met en valeur l'état du sujet. La seconde phrase met en valeur les qualités supposées du sujet.

Comment: *Il est professeur*, d'accord, mais *il est un professeur* et *il est le professeur*, ça ne me parait pas du tout idiomatique. On dit *c'est un professeur*, *c'est le professeur*, non ?

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu un francophone dire *il est **un** professeur ou il est **un** fugitif*, c'est une faute courante des apprenants. [Le complément prédicatif est construit sans article lorsqu'il exprime l'appartenance, au sens abstrait, à certaines catégories humaines, telles que les professions, les statuts sociaux, les groupes d'âge, les nationalités ou les catégories de malades](http://gabrielwyler.com/page044.html)

Comment: La traduction dans la question originale ("He is classically trained") est tout à fait correcte.

Comment: Pas de problème avec Natacha, mais je n'ai entendu dire *Il est **un** champion* (au lieu de *c'est un champion*) que de la bouche de personnes dont le français n'est pas la langue maternelle.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the translation you found, I would rather translate the following sentence:

> Il est de formation classique.

By:

> He did a classic training.

Comment: This translation isn't idiomatic English and doesn't correspond to the original French.

Comment: @Théophile > I can't tell myself how idiomatic it is in English but for the "translation" part, it conveys the same meaning, or at least as a non-native speaker I understand it the same.

Comment: @LaurentS. To give a bit more detail: to say "he did *a* training" sounds like a single instance, as in a workshop, as opposed to a general education. Second, *classic* isn't quite the same as *classical* (although both are *classique* in French): *classic* means "standard", "typical", "predictable" (e.g., "a classic excuse"). If you look at Google's [n-gram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams) you will see that "classical education" and "classical training" are the usual expressions for this reason. In short, to translate back into French: "Il a suivi une séance de formation typique."

Answer (score 1):

**He is of a delicate constitution.**

This is admittedly a somewhat archaic construction, but you can see that *of* here plays the same functional role, and occurs at the same place in the construction, as *de* in French.

Comment: La question porte sur la structure grammaticale de « Il est de formation classique. » Je ne vois pas de relation entre la question et ta réponse.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to think of it in a more literal sense would be:

> He is of a classical training

"De" is showing that he is **from** a classical origin here. The "from" is key to understanding the meaning.

Comment: I think that *from* is too literal. I'd say the construction is more like the *of* in "He is *of* the opinion that ...", which we could rephrase as "His opinion is ...". Similarly, "His training is classical".

Comment: @Théophile You're right, but I think it helps people learning French as a way to see *why that rearrangement functions*. Like "Je suis **d**'avis que"; in more formal registers of English, one sometimes hears "I am **of** the opinion that". That's just my way of thinking about/remembering what those mean.